# Enterprise Architect and Subversion

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to allow work with Subversion within Enterprise Architect, and I'm having some problems:

I created an eap file, imported it, and then checked out the file and opened it in Enterprise Architect.
I then configured the version control settings of the project, and directed it to my SVN client.
I picked a package, used "Add Branch To Version Control", then "check out". I've made some changes and then "check in".
In my subversion log I saw that files were indeed checked in.
Then, using Subversion, I checked out a clean copy, and opened the eap file.
To my surprise, none of the changes (or my baselines) were shown there. But after I did "Get Latest" - the changes were there (but not the baseline).

What am I doing wrong? Is it supposed to be like that? Because I expect that when I check out a clean copy it will be the most updated. Isn't that the case in Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intended use of external version control (CVS, Subversion, TFS, etc) is to version-control individual packages, but not the .EAP file. "Get Latest" and the other version-control commands only work on packages, they have no effect on the .EAP file.

This way each modeller maintains their own .EAP file, and chooses which versions of which controlled packages to include and where in their EA project they should be placed. You are also free to have several different .EAP files yourself, of course.

So think of the .EAP file as the directory where you would normally check out a Subversion tree. That directory itself does not get checked into the repository, and you can check the same stuff out into several different directories if you wish.

This approach (which is one of three ways to achieve team modelling with EA) does mean that certain things which are stored in the .EAP file don't get version-controlled at all, mainly project settings of various kinds. If you have a specific need to store those, first look into if they can be exported from EA (check the help file for "export reference data").

If you still end up needing to store the project itself, I'd place it in a different Subversion directory that doesn't get tagged and branched with the packages; that just gets confusing.

Finally, if you're setting up a Subversion repository just for your models, I recommend you take a look at EA's baseline functionality as well. It's a different way to do version control which doesn't involve Subversion and in my opinion is easier to manage - but you need to make certain you have a working backup policy in place for your .EAP file.

Comment: Thank you. But again - isn't it fair to assume that when I check out a clean copy I'll get the latest version (the data is stored in the XML files anyway)? Why do I need to "Get latest" in order to see the latest changes even when I check out a clean copy?

Answer (score 1):

a/ use a context menu "Package control > File properties" ... to get a name of locked file

b/ find this file in your local SVN

c/ use SVN context menu, "SVN Get Lock" with checked option "Steal the locks"

d/ then you can release lock in SVN via "Release lock..." or directly use Check in EA etc.

Note: I use a Tortoise SVN.